# Complex sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I need some help with a SQL query I'm working on. Here is a simplified version of the data I'm working with. I have 3 tables:

**Contacts**:

```
- ContactID
- ContactName
```

**Submissions**:

```
- SubmissionID
- ContactID
- SubmissionTypeID
```

**SubmissionTypes**:

```
- SubmissionTypeID
- SubmissionType
```

I need to return all of the Contacts (joined to `Submissions` on `ContactID`) where there are `SubmissionTypeIDs` that match up with a list of `SubmissionTypeIDs`. The tricky part is that I only want results where a Contact has a Submission record with a `SubmissionTypeID` that matches each of the values in the list. So, for instance, if I had this data:

```
Contacts
----------------
1 | Jim Johnson
2 | Sally Anderson

SubmissionTypes
----------------------
1 | Contact Form
2 | Request Form   
3 | Generic Form

Submissions
----------------------
1 | 1 | 1 
2 | 1 | 2  
3 | 2 | 1
```

If my `SubmissionTypeID` values are 1 and 2, I'd want to get the following results:

```
Jim Johnson | Contact Form 
Jim Johnson | Request Form
```

I wouldn't want to see Sally Anderson because she doesn't have a record in Submissions for both values.

I'm guessing there are a few ways to do this. I'm excited to see your ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is with INTERSECT:

```
select c.contactname, t.submissiontype
  from contacts c
  join submissions s
    on c.contactid = s.contactid
  join submissiontypes t
    on s.submissiontypeid = t.submissiontypeid
  join (select c.contactid
          from contacts c
          join submissions s
            on c.contactid = s.contactid
         where s.submissiontypeid = 1
        intersect
        select c.contactid
          from contacts c
          join submissions s
            on c.contactid = s.contactid
         where s.submissiontypeid = 2) v
    on c.contactid = v.contactid
 where s.submissiontypeid in (1, 2)
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ee4e/2/0

You can also COUNT where equal to 2 (you have 2 values you're checking for):

```
select c.contactname, t.submissiontype
  from contacts c
  join submissions s
    on c.contactid = s.contactid
  join submissiontypes t
    on s.submissiontypeid = t.submissiontypeid
  join (select c.contactid
          from contacts c
          join submissions s
            on c.contactid = s.contactid
         where s.submissiontypeid in (1, 2)
         group by c.contactid
        having count(distinct s.submissiontypeid) = 2) v
    on c.contactid = v.contactid
 where s.submissiontypeid in (1, 2)
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ee4e/1/0

Comment: depending on other constraints, `having count(*) = 2` might need to be `having count(distinct submissiontypeid) = 2`. +1 for `intersect`, though.

Comment: @Laurence agreed, normally I would do without distinct by default but I just edited it as there's probably a decent chance a contact could have more than one submission of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a convoluted way using double negation.

```
declare @list table (SubmissionTypeID int not null primary key);

insert into @list values (1), (2); -- values to search for.

with c as (
    select
        c.ContactID,
        c.ContactName
    from
        Contacts c
    where
        not exists (
            select
                'x'
            from
                @list l
            where
                not exists (
                    select
                        'x'
                    from
                        Submissions s
                    where
                        s.ContactID = c.ContactID and
                        s.SubmissionTypeID = l.SubmissionTypeID
                )
        )
)
select
    c.ContactName,
    t.SubmissionType
from
    c
        inner join
    Submissions s
        on c.ContactId = s.ContactId
        inner join
    SubmissionTypes t
        on s.SubmissionTypeID = t.SubmissionTypeID
        inner join
    @list l
        on t.SubmissionTypeID = l.SubmissionTypeID;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4669/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.. It works fine to me 

DECLARE @list TABLE (SubmissionTypeID int not null primary key);

INSERT INTO @list VALUES(1); -- values to search for.

SELECT C.ContactName, ST.SubmissionTypeName
FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S.ContactID ORDER BY S.ContactID) AS RCount
FROM 
Submission S
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @list l WHERE l.SubmissionTypeID = S.SubmissionTypeID)) AS Result
INNER JOIN Submission S1 ON S1.ContactID = Result.ContactID
INNER JOIN Contacts C ON C.ContactID = Result.ContactID
INNER JOIN SubmissionTypes ST ON ST.SubmissionTypeID = S1.SubmissionTypeID
WHERE RCOunt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubmissionTypeID) FROM @list)
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @list l WHERE l.SubmissionTypeID = ST.SubmissionTypeID)
;
```